# Start-Process as another user with Credentials and ArgumentList

Tags: powershell

I am currently facing the issue of running an .exe as another user. I followed the documentation and all the given suggestion in the internet, but still cannot run it successfully as another user with arguments.

Need some advise on how to resolve this. I am using powershell v4. Much help appreciated. Thank you.

```
$username = 'wintel\approveduser'
$password = 'password123'
$securePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $password -AsPlainText -Force
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential $username, $securePassword

Start-Process -FilePath D:\testing\CICD.exe -Credential $credential -ArgumentList "-i -b CICDbranch -m Release -r -f $currentPath\Release\export.zip" -RedirectStandardOutput ".\stdout.txt"
```

Comment: Do you get any errors or any output from your script?

Comment: What makes you think you "cannot run it successfully"? What is the expected behavior? What is the actual behavior? If you're getting errors: what do they say?

Comment: It is in an infinite loop. Actually I just want to check syntax wise is the code fine?

Comment: The expected behavior is that the script will be able run the .exe as another user with arguments, which is listed in the argumentList